# Legend disappears when I fill the bars on ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to draw a multi layered pie chart using the following code

```
df <- data.frame(a = c(4, 3, 3, 8, 1, 1, 10),
                 b = c("x", "x", "x", "y", "y", "y", "z"),
                 c = c("x1", "x2", "x3", "y1", "y2", "y3", "z1"))

ggplot(df, aes(x = b, y = a, fill = c))+
  geom_bar(stat = "identity",
           color = "black", 
           fill = c("yellow","blue","black","green","red","white","black"))+
  coord_polar(theta="y")
```

The thing is, when I add the fill variable into the geom_bar I lose the legend, and can't add it at all, tried adding `scale_fill_manual()` as some suggested but it still doesn't work for me, any idea why this is happening?

PS: is it possible to remove the spaces between each bar/circle?

Comment: Please add a simple data.frame for `df`. What do you want the fill to represent? You have it both as `fill=c` and `fill=yellow` which I think means it ignores the different levels of `c`

Comment: I apologize, i forgot to enter the df part, also this is a simplistic example, I actually have a fully fledged coloring scheme, but i wanted the code to be simple in the question (I improved it now)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the second `fill` argument, the one in `geom_bar`.

```
library(ggplot2)
    df <- data.frame(a = c(4, 3, 3, 8, 1, 1, 10),
                     b = c("x", "x", "x", "y", "y", "y", "z"),
                     c = c("x1", "x2", "x3", "y1", "y2", "y3", "z1")
                     )

    ggplot(df, aes(x = b, y = a, fill = c))+
      geom_bar(stat = "identity",
               width=1,#set width to remove white space, b/c the default is 0.9
               color = "black",)+
      coord_polar(theta="y")+ #Note you don't need the scale_fill_manual below; if omitted, r uses the default palette
      scale_fill_manual(values = c("yellow","blue","black","green","red","white","black"))

    )
```

Result:

[image]